how to sql database access using managed identity for particular database in .net core?
I have sql server level mapped managed identity and i access and authenticate sql server using .net core.but my requirement is to access for only managed identity sql databases.
Case 1:sql server => A And B databases.if i apply managed identity for server.
1)"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=A;"
2)"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=B;"
both are accessed.but i want to access permission databases only.
